# Explanation of a Ram Utilization script

Tags: bash, scripts, ram, find, optimization

As an answer to question [Lots of ram. How to use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196412/lots-of-ram-how-to-use-it/197417#197417), I saw this script.

```
 find /home/user/.config/ /home/user/.gconf/ /home/user/.mozilla/ /usr/share/icons/current_icon_theme/ /usr/share/nautilus/ /usr/bin/nau* /usr/share/gnome* /usr/bin/gno* /usr/lib/ -xdev -type f -exec cat '{}' \; > /dev/null
```

Could someone explain what that line does? It also has an accompanying autostartup script.

```
sh -c "sleep 8; /path/to/the/script.sh" &
```

Comment: It waits 8 seconds, then launches the script.

Answer (score 2):

By making `cat` read those files, it is loading all those commands into the RAM cache. The intention is to make all those files already in the cache when some application actually requests any of them. [Another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/196425/158442) to that post explains this.